# Splitting number of records into groups?

Tags: php

I have a large number of records in the CSV file.

I am trying to implement multiple Insert into single query but I need to workout how many single query I need base on Total records.

For example:

```
$totalRecord = 1620;
```

So I need 17 queries. 16 query will have 100 Insert records and 17th query will have 20 records.

The number of `$totalRecord` can be anything between 1 to 500,00

How to work this out?

Eg:

```
Query 1:
INSERT INTO [table] 
( [field1], [field2], [field3] ) VALUES 
( '[value1.1]', '[value1.2]', '[value1.3]' ), 
( '[value2.1]', '[value2.2]', '[value2.3]' ), 
( '[value3.1]', '[value3.2]', '[value3.3]' ),

Query 2: 
INSERT INTO [table] 
( [field1], [field2], [field3] ) VALUES 
( '[value1.1]', '[value1.2]', '[value1.3]' ), 
( '[value2.1]', '[value2.2]', '[value2.3]' ), 
( '[value3.1]', '[value3.2]', '[value3.3]' ),
```

Comment: Is this a one-off operation, or will you be doing it often? If one-off, it's much better to import to your database directly from the CSV, or in code, easier to use fgetcsv() and insert in a loop.

Comment: @Michael It will be quite often like once every week.  This is what I am doing `fgetcsv()` and insert in a loop but over 100,000 records is too slow. So I need to groups multiple of insert queries. How to calculate how many groups I need?

Comment: maybe read about prepared statements ? link -> http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: why would you want to know how many records you have? make a prepared statement and loop the values + stmt->execute ; read the above link

Answer (score 2):

Use Modulus and Division:

```
$recordsineachquery = 100;
$recordsinlastquery = $totalrecords % $recordsineachquery;
$fullqueries = ($totalrecords - $recordsinlastquery) / $recordsineachquery;
$totalqueries = $fullqueries + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use integer division to find your number of groups and the modulus operator to find out how many inserts are in your last set:

```
// You have to round the division result because PHP doesn't do integer division.
$numGroups = (int)($totalRecords / 100);
$remainder = $totalRecords % 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$batchProcessLimit = 100;
$batchStep = 0;

$query = "INSERT INTO [table] ( [field1], [field2], [field3] ) VALUES ";

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    $query .= "( '[value1.1]', '[value1.2]', '[value1.3]' )"

    if ($batchProcessLimit % ++$batchStep != 0) $query .= ",";
    else
    {
        // execute the query

        $query = "INSERT INTO [table] ( [field1], [field2], [field3] ) VALUES ";
    }
}

// execute the query for remaining rows
```